# How to create OSL Refraction shader

Tags: osl

Is it possible to create a refraction shader using OSL with parameters to control the angle it refracts to using the normal and the angle of incidence?

Comment: See if this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/osl-and-raytracing?rq=1

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question